# Display data from two different models in one html table using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models namely StudentInfo & StudentAdmission.
student_id is foreign key in StudentAdmission model.
I want to display the values of both models together in one html table.
How could I do that.

models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    gender_choice = (
        ("male", "Male"),
        ("Female", "Female"),
    )
    
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choice, max_length=10)
    dob = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname

class StudentAdmission(models.Model):
    class_choice = (
        ("one", "one"),
        ("two", "two"),
        ("three", "three"),
    )
    
    section_choice = (
        ("A", "A"),
        ("B", "B"),
        ("C", "C"),
    )
    
    transport_choice1 = (
        ("abc", "abc"),
        ("bcd", "bcd"),
        ("def", "def"),
    )

    transport_choice2 = (
        ("ab", "ab"),
        ("bc", "bc"),
        ("de", "de"),
    )
    
    admission_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    admission_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_name = models.CharField(choices=class_choice, max_length=10)
    section_name = models.CharField(choices=section_choice, max_length=10)
    transportation = models.CharField(choices=transport_choice1, max_length=10)
    transport_vehicle = models.CharField(choices=transport_choice2, max_length=10)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

view.py:

```
def student_list(request):
    students = StudentInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    data = {
        "students": students,
    }
    return render(request, "students/student_list.html", data)
```

student_list.html

```
{% if students %}
    {% for student in students %}
        <tr>
            <td>
              #0021
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {% if student.photo %}
                    <img src="{{ student.photo.url }}" alt="student">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="{% static 'img/default-pic.png' %}" alt="student">
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{student.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
            <td>class name</td>
            <td>section name</td>
            <td>Jack Sparrow </td>
            <td>{{student.address}}</td>
            <td>{{student.dob}}</td>
            <td>{{student.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{student.email}}</td>
            
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[I want to display related class_name and section_name in following table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM8LS.png)

Comment: add your view or template show what you tried

Comment: @Blackranger I have added view and template, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to related object via `RELATED_MODEL_NAME_set`. Here for example it's `studentadmission_set`

Or you can set your own related name in your `models.py`:

```py
class StudentAdmission(models.Model):
    ...
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="admissions")
```

After that, you can access to related model with this value

```
...
{% for admission in student.admissions.all %}
... Do sth
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: I get the following error now:      'RelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry! i've edited my answer. Note that each student has a few admissions, so take care of how you want to show them in table @Rafiullah

Comment: Glad to hear that @Rafiullah